# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined (but works in jsfiddle?)

Tags: jquery

I've just been working on a little animated effect for my navigation.
However I've run into an issue with the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined" that chrome console is throwing at me regarding line 5:

`var left = $('nav').find('.current_page_item').position().left;`

If I enter the selector into the console manually, then I get the expected 0 return string, yet it just doesn't want to play ball.

I then took it to jsfiddle to play around with it...  and it works without a problem there!
found here: http://jsfiddle.net/5wPQa/594/

Any insight would be amazing

EDIT:
Fix was in the comments below.. just a simple document.ready
Two eyes are always better that one!

Comment: Try to warap your code in document.ready function, here is the same issue: http://jsfiddle.net/G8Jtw/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the default options on jsfiddle.

Comment: Well... that did it!
I knew it would be something simple I overlooked, it just threw me that jsfiddle worked haha!
Gotta love that second pair of eyes
thank you very much :)

Comment: You don't need to put "solved" in the title, SO handles that.

Comment: wow. I always thought that was something I had to do! haha.
The more we know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to warap your code in `document.ready` function, your fiddle works because by default jsfiddle wraps your code in `onLoad` handler (but you can change it).

Here is the same issue by setting `No wrap <in head>`: http://jsfiddle.net/G8Jtw/

If you wrap the code in document.ready it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8QeVd/

Final code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // insert slider
    $('nav ul').append('<div id="slider"></div>');

    // initially reset
    var left = $('nav').find('.current_page_item').position().left;
    var width = $('nav ul li:first-child a').width();
    $('#slider').css({
        'left': left,
        'width': width
    });

    // sliding
    $('nav ul li a').hover(function () {

        var left = $(this).parent().position().left;
        var width = $(this).width();

        $('#slider').stop().animate({
            'left': left,
                'width': width
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jsfiddle has the (perhaps confusing) default of wrapping your code in a `window.load` handler. I'm going to guess that you are attempting to access `nav` or `.current_page_item` before they exist. Try wrapping your code in a dom ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: That was indeed it, had never noticed that about jsfiddle before.
Going to mark Irvins answer as the accepted as he beat you to it by just a bit.
Much appreciated though! thank you